# AWS SDK failing to get credentials in React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm building a React app which I need to connect to a database and storage on AWS. I've followed the instructions but for some reason the `aws-sdk` cannot retrieve my credentials which I've set in my shared credentials file. I've tried running the following in a blank node project:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  // credentials not loaded
  else {
    console.log("Access key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
    console.log("Secret access key:", AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey);
  }
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

s3.listBuckets((err, data) => {
    err ?
        console.log('Error: ', err) :
        console.log('Success: ', data.Buckets);
});
```

and here is the successful result:

```
λ node test.js
Access key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Secret access key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Success:  [
  { 
    Name: 'cube-logo',
    CreationDate: 2018-11-16T15:08:28.000Z
  },
  {
    Name: 'jigsaw-image-library',
    CreationDate: 2020-05-20T10:36:56.000Z
  }
]
```

This test works perfectly. Not only can I retrieve my credentials, but I can also instatiate a new S3 object and list my Buckets 'jigsaw-image-library' and 'cube-logo'. But in React, all I get is this console error:

```
CredentialsError: No credentials to load
    at credError (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/1.chunk.js:6915:40)
    at Config.getCredentials (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/1.chunk.js:6960:14)
    at Module../src/components/App/App.js (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/main.chunk.js:1053:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:785:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:151:20)
    at Module../src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/main.chunk.js:2564:77)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:785:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:151:20)
    at Object.1 (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/main.chunk.js:4047:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:785:30)
    at checkDeferredModules (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:46:23)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/bundle.js:33:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/jigsaw/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:65
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Node.js has access to your local machine and any credentials file stored on it, while the React app is running in a browser, presumably, so doesn't have access to the local drive. PS the `aws-SDK` package name should be `aws-sdk`.

Comment: regarding the naming - sorry that was an editing error I made - now corrected. The React app is running in Node using ```create-react-app``` etc. In the test Node script I made, it had no problem logging my credentials to the console. I assumed the same would be true in the React app, as I followed all the instructions on the AWS docs.

Comment: thinking about it some  more, i know what you mean by running in the browser, rather than in Node on the command line. I assumed I would follow instructions for Node.js because I'm building a React app in Node.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to supply AWS credentials to your React app. Hard-coding them is not advisable. You can ask the user to supply them or use some form of identity federation so your user can log in and get temporary AWS credentials. Also look at Amplify, which can help you solve authentication and storage challenges.

Comment: Check out https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrate-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-into-a-react-app/